# java connection to sql server using windows authentication

Tags: java, sql

try to connect java to sql  Server

```
package sd;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=P_Cat_tweets;integratedSecurity=true");
            System.out.println("test");
            Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
            String Sql = "select * from teewts";
            ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);

            System.out.println(rs.next());
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:
`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:` The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".

Comment: Is your connection string valid? Are you able to connect to sql server from management studio? or is it behind a firewall? Please check all these.

Comment: Did you check all things mentioned in the error? Can you connect with SQL Server authenticatin?

Comment: @PradeepSimha yes i can connect to sql server from management studio

Comment: @shree.pat18 i never used Server authenticatin.

Comment: @KevoniaTomlinson Windows authentication can fail if the server and client are not in same domain. If you can connect with username and password, that could be a possible cause of error.